# Get SwiftCSV Up and Running?

Tags: ios, macos, swift, csv

I'm trying to use SwiftCSV by naoty to read a .csv file. I successfully installed the whole thing via Cocoapods, but when I try to use the sample code from Github, the sample "users.csv" file doesn't seem to parse. In my viewDidLoad() function, I copied all of the sample code below.  The project builds and runs just fine.

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "users.csv") {
    var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
        if let csv = CSV(contentsOfURL: url, error: error) {
            // Rows
            let rows = csv.rows
            let headers = csv.headers  //=> ["id", "name", "age"]
            let alice = csv.rows[0]    //=> ["id": "1", "name": "Alice", "age": "18"]
            let bob = csv.rows[1]      //=> ["id": "2", "name": "Bob", "age": "19"]

            // Columns
            let columns = csv.columns
            let names = csv.columns["name"]  //=> ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"]
            let ages = csv.columns["age"]    //=> ["18", "19", "20"]
         }
     }
 }
```

users.csv:

```
id,name,age
1,Alice,18
2,Bob,19
3,Charlie,20
```

I added a couple of println statements to the end of the block. Here's my output, and the output the sample says I should get.

```
println(headers)
```

output: [ ]  (Should be: ["id", "name", "age"])

```
println(names)
```

output: nil  (Should be: ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"])

The line

```
let alice = csv.rows[0]
```

also crashes the application with "fatal error: Array index out of range" unless I comment it out. Same with Bob.

What am I doing wrong?